# Automatically Generate a Reference based on Values in other Columns

Tags: vba, ms-access, automation, reference

I am fully aware that there are similar questions asked on this platform before, but the answers do not necessarily stick to the exact question, hence me asking the question again.

### What am I trying to accomplish?

I am creating a genealogical name index database.

The reference which should be automatically generated in the reference column should take the first three letter of the surname field (eg. JOO) and add a number sequence to it (eg. 0001), **BUT** the number sequence must depend on the first three letters of the surname and not just increase with +1 for every new record.

The table consist out of the following columns:

- A reference field, which should contain the formulated, automatically generated, reference.
- Surname
- Given Name(s)
- Etc...

**Example of how it should work:**

The following records (entered in the same order as shown) contain the surnames (in the surnames field):

1. Jooste
2. Jooste
3. Wessels
4. Potgieter
5. Jooste

Their references that should be generated **should** look as follow:

1. JOO0001
2. JOO0002
3. WES0001
4. POT0001
5. JOO0003

Their references that should be generated **should not** look as follow:

1. JOO0001
2. JOO0002
3. WES0003
4. POT0004
5. JOO0005

This is caused by the following formula (which I've tried):

```
reference = Left(Surname, 3) & Right("000" & CStr(CInt(Nz(DMax("right(reference,4)", "relatives_tbl"), 0)) + 1), 4)
```

### Why am I trying to accomplish this?

The main reason why I need the reference number to be formulated is to make future referencing easier in the future.  This way the reference number will be as short as possible because you easily get to 30'000 people in total but highly unlikely more than 9999 of one surname.

I have tried the formula mentioned above, which does not give me the desired outcome.  I hope my question is clear and logical and I am looking forward to your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the third argument of `DMax`, which acts as a `WHERE` clause:

```
Function fGetSurnameID(strSurname As String) As String
    fGetSurnameID = UCase(Left(strSurname, 3)) & Format(Nz(DMax("right(SurnameID,3)", "tblSurname", "Left(Surname,3)='" & Left(strSurname, 3) & "'"), 0) + 1, "000")
End Function
```

Or, if you are calling this from a command button on a form, then you could do:

```
Private Sub submit_btn_Click()
    member_ID = UCase(Left(Surname, 3)) & Format(Nz(DMax("right(Member_ID,3)", "relatives_tbl", "Left(Surname,3)='" & Left(Surname, 3) & "'"), 0) + 1, "000")
End Sub
```

However, storing two pieces of information in the same field can often be a bad idea within a database. Additionally, you will need to consider how you handle any surnames that have less than 3 characters.

Also, using `reference` as a field name could cause problems, as it is a reserved word in Access.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Should I copy and paste your formula as is?  Should I still replace and/or rename certain information?

Comment: You can paste this function into a module, so that you can call it from anywhere within the database. You will need to replace the fields and table in the `DMax` part with your own.

Comment: I took your advice, renamed the [tag:reference] and adjusted the code as follow: `Private Sub submit_btn_Click()
member_ID = UCase(Left(Surname, 3)) & Format(Nz(DMax("right(Surname,3)", "relatives_tbl", "Left(Surname,3)='" & Left(Surname, 3) & "'"), 0) + 1, "000")
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub` but if I want to enter the second person of the same surname I get a "Type Mismatch" error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Rather than `Right(Surname,3)` in the `DMax`, it should have been `Right(Member_ID,3)`. Answer has been corrected.